# How do I slow down a nested for loop?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a javascript program that will count in base 16:

This code works but the for loops are WAAYYY too fast to be rendered on screen in the HTML, even on a very fast computer, so please tell me a way to slow down these for loops.

```js
// Run this program at 60 fps
let frameRate = 1000 / 60;

// Have a boolean variable called isClicked that tracks if the user has clicked the button
let isClicked = false;

let integer = 0;

// Have the base 16 numbers be strings
let b16num1 = "";
let b16num2 = "";


// Have an array of all of the valid base16 numbers
let valid = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

const ClickButton = function() {
  isClicked = true;
}

const runProgram = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < valid.length; i++) {
    b16num1 = valid[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < valid.length; j++) {
      b16num2 = valid[j];
    }
  }
}

const updateHTML = function() {
  let base16text = document.getElementById("base16text");
  base16text.innerHTML = b16num1 + b16num2;
}

// Check if the user has clicked the button if they did then it runs the program
const checkIfClicked = function() {
  // Run this if statement only once and check if its clicked
  if (isClicked && integer < 1) {
    // Run the program and update the HTML
    setInterval(updateHTML, frameRate);
    runProgram();
    integer++;
    // Stop repeating this function for a performance boost
    clearInterval(repeat);
  }
}
// Repeat the checkIfClicked function over and over again
let repeat = setInterval(checkIfClicked, frameRate);
```

```html
<button onclick="ClickButton()">Count in base 16!</button>
<br>
<h1 id="base16text"></h1>
```

Comment: Isn't frameRate your problem? You have it at 60 times a second?

Comment: you are updating each 16.6 miliseconds, so increase frameRate

Comment: I've tried slowing down the frame rate and that doesn't do anything.

Comment: I've tried both 1 fps and 100 fps and their is no difference.

Comment: `runProgram` is unaffected by frameRate

Comment: so much redundant and wrong in that code - see https://jsfiddle.net/dxc95Lsk/

Comment: or even https://jsfiddle.net/qvmqcmkv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that every time your function calls `runProgram()` ,Which happens 16.6 times a second, it counts all the way up! Then entire for loop runs and thus counts all the way to 255. The issue isn't with the frame rate, it's that the program counts all the way up before you can even see it.

try this:

```
// Run this program at 60 fps
let frameRate = 1000 / 20;
var value = 0;
var repeat;

const startCounting = function()
{
    repeat = setInterval(updateHtml, frameRate);
}

const updateHtml = function()
{
    if (value < 255)
    {
        value++;
        let base16text = document.getElementById("base16text");
        base16text.innerHTML = value.toString(16).toUpperCase();
    }
    else
    {
        clearInterval(repeat);
    }
}
```

This adds 1 to your number every time the function is called! Also the toString automatically converts between bases for you. So that's pretty handy.

Comment: Wait... what if i wanted to add more strings so the maximum value is "FFFF" or something could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: I made some significant upgrades to my code with some help from Jaromanda X's comment. (You should look at his) But his code is still even better than mine. You can increase what the function counts to by increasing the 255 to something bigger!